# Help!: rosinstall_generator generating an empty rosinstall file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I am trying to install the Desktop version of Hydro on Mac OS X using Homebrew. I am following the instructions as mentioned on the installation page. But when I try to generate the rosinstall file for downloading and building the ROS stack, my rosinstall_generator command for desktop version generates an empty file with following prompt: No packages/stacks left after applying the exclusions

As mentioned on the installation page, here is the command I used: **rosinstall_generator desktop --rosdistro hydro --deps --dry-only > hydro-desktop-dry.rosinstall**

I did install rosinstall_generator using pip in the earlier steps. Still, I tried updating it using the pip. Did anyone else face this issue? What am I missing over here?

Thanks,
Jasprit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84826/help!:-rosinstall_generator-generating-an-empty-rosinstall-file/) by [jaspritsgill](https://answers.ros.org/users/7141/jaspritsgill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're asking for desktop with the --dry-only option.  However there are no dry packages in desktop which is why it is giving you an empty list.  You should be using --wet-only.

See the instructions here: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source for hydro on OS X.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jaspritsgill](https://answers.ros.org/users/7141/jaspritsgill/) on 2013-09-30**:
I am trying to build the rosbuild packages, hence --dry-only. The instructions say that for BARE-BONES no dry packages are required but desktop does. is that changed in hydo? For building catkin wrkspces I did use --wet-only. I will try proceeding if there are no packages for Desktop too.

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-01**:
I am having the same issue, trying to install full-desktop. Im getting "No packages/stacks left after applying the exclusions". Is this situation normal?

**Comment by [jaspritsgill](https://answers.ros.org/users/7141/jaspritsgill/) on 2013-10-01**:
It seems so. I checked for full-desktop too and I got the same. I guess there are no dry packages for Hydro desktop, as tfoote mentioned. The installation instructions are not updated it seems. I proceeded with the installation with no dry packages and it seems to be working fine so far.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-01**:
The instructions were out of date.  That is expected as there are no released rosbuild packages in hydro.  I've updated the instructions to make a note and remove the out of date lines.

**Comment by [jaspritsgill](https://answers.ros.org/users/7141/jaspritsgill/) on 2013-10-03**:
Thanks tfoote!